# SQL, how to insert all rows of a table into another one

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

OK so I suck at SQL and I always have to ask for help, let me show my problem.
I have 2 tables, here is the structure for both:

- **ID** (int)
- courseID (int)
- course (bit)
- bookmark (varchar(100))
- course_date (datetime)
- posttest (bit)
- post_attempts (int)

Now I need to move all rows of one table to the other one (not update), just to have only one table with all rows of both.
The ID column is a primary key with auto increment, but when I tried to use `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2`, sql generates this error **#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'**.

Comment: Do you care about whether the id gets copied across from the old table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `table1` has an identity on `ID`, you should just select all columns except the `ID`

```
INSERT INTO table1(
    course_id,
    course,
    bookmark,
    course_date,
    posttest,
    post_attempts
)
SELECT
    course_id,
    course,
    bookmark,
    course_date,
    posttest,
    post_attempts
FROM table2
```

Comment: Thanks that's works pretty well...but why the ID of inserted rows starts counting from 10000? Is there a way to insert rows in a new table from a specific number ID?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the ID from the old table transferring across, you can use this:

```
INSERT INTO newTable (courseID, course, bookmark, course_date, posttest, post_attempts)
SELECT courseID, course, bookmark, course_date, posttest, post_attempts
FROM oldTable;
```

This will transfer all columns except ID, which should solve the issue.